# Supremum of uniformly Lipschitz functions is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions

If we have a set of functions $f_i$ such that every $f_i$ has a common Lipschitz constant $M$, is it true that the supremum of these functions at some $x$ is also Lipschitz? Assume that we can uniformly bound all the functions by $K$.

The first part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601575/is-the-supremum-of-a-family-of-locally-lipschitz-functions-always-locally-lipsch) suggests it is true, so I tried to do a little triangle inequality manipulation with this, similar to how one might prove that $fg$ or $f + g$ are Lipschitz assuming $f, g$ Lipschitz and bounded. However, I had trouble with finding the common term. What are some other approaches to this proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) := \sup\{f_i(x) : i\in I\}$. Let $x,y$ be arbitrary. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $i\in I$ such that $f(x)-\epsilon\le f_i(x)$. Hence
\begin{align*}
f(x)-f(y)
&\le f_i(x)-f(y) + \epsilon\le f_i(x)-f_i(y) + \epsilon\\
&\le |f_i(x)-f_i(y)| + \epsilon \le M|x-y| + \epsilon.
\end{align*}
Since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f(x)-f(y)\le M|x-y|$. Interchanging the roles of $x$ and $y$ shows that also $f(y)-f(x)\le M|x-y|$, hence $|f(x)-f(y)|\le M|x-y|$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a small question. How do we know that $f(x) - \epsilon \leq f_i(x)$ must hold? Is it because $f(x)$ is arbitrarily close to any of the $f_i(x)$? I guess it it intuitively makes sense but I am not sure how to state that formally

Comment: $f(x)$ is the smallest upper bound of the $f_i(x)$. If there were no $i$ such that $f(x)-\epsilon\le f_i(x)$, then $f_i(x)<f(x)-\epsilon$ for all $i$ such that $f(x)-\epsilon/2$ would be a smaller upper bound. Contradiction.

Comment: Ah, I see. Also, why may we assume that $f(y) - \epsilon \leq f_i(y)$, the same $i$ as the one used for $f(x)$?

Comment: No, can be another $i$. The result in the end is without $i$.

Comment: But isn't the Lipschitz condition that $|f_i(x) - f_i(y)| \leq M|x - y|$ for a given $f_i$? How do we know that $|f_i(x) - f_j(y)| \leq M|x-y|$ as well?

Comment: Oh, now I see where your question came from. It is the $-f(y)\le -f_i(y)$ in the first line, right? This is equivalent to $f(y)\ge f_i(y)$. And this is because?